# Bash for loop with multiple file extensions provided as variable

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I am trying to process files under a `/data/` directory by filtering through multiple files extension in for loop, I am trying to provide the pattern as a variable but for some reason it does not like it.

### This does not work

```bash
data="/data"
file_pattern=*.{json,yaml}
for file in "$data"/$file_pattern; do
  echo "File processed"
done
```

### This works

```bash
data="/data"
for file in "$data"/*.{json,yaml}; do
  echo "File processed"
done
```

### This also works

```bash
data="/data"
file_pattern=*.json
for file in "$data"/$file_pattern; do
  echo "File processed"
done
```

Comment: If you check your command at https://www.shellcheck.net/ it will explain why your command isn't working (i.e. "Brace expansions and globs are literal in assignments. Quote it or use an array.")

Comment: Also, [3.5 Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) in the bash manual: because brace expansion happens first, after parameter expansion its too late for the braces to have any effect.